# Building dependency package from within node_modules

Tags: javascript, npm, continuous-integration, node-modules

Current project I'm working on has a dependency inside `node_modules`, as part of the CI process, we `cd` into the module's folder and run `npm install` followed by running the module's build script with `npm build` and then move the build artifact back to the main project folder, where it can be used as a kind of "sub-application".

This seems really inefficient to me, at the least it seems unorthodox, and has me worried, but for certain reasons, seems to be the simplest solution to the problem we're faced with.

Are there any hidden gotchas associated with this approach? Will doing this potentially come back to bite me later on or any caveats I should be aware of?